# Twitter API Protected User Rate Limit

Tags: api, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I get mixed results when I try this so I thought I'd ask if anyone else knows of any documentation, etc that explains what happens - the problem is when you access a protected users feed on Twitter, does that count towards your API rate limit?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Twitter's [documentation page for user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) , it is counted towards your rate limit. Regardless of whether the user is protected or public.

> Rate Limited
>
> true

Comment: As of 2017-02-25, the link is broken.